# Cartthrob: How do I set the VAT for not logged in visitors?

Tags: cartthrob

I have big problems how to figure out the taxt (VAT) system, I do not understand anything. The settings are very confusing.

How do I set a basic tax for non-logged in visitors?
And why must I set my global rates on New York? This shop shall work in the Netherlands, there is no option for other countries than in the US.

Thanks a lot for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you've uploaded the CartThrob themes folder to

your_site_root > themes > third_party > cartthrob

To make sure that the settings javascript is available (the settings don't work correctly if it's not uploaded)

1. cartthrob settings > global > default location

set your default country to the Netherlands (or other country as needed). This way CT will assume that anyone visiting is starting from the Netherlands, even if they are not logged in, and there is no default location data to work with.

1. Go to cartthrob settings > taxes > tax by location - percentage (i'm assuming this will work for VAT. CT doesn't include a VAT specific tax plugin, but typically it's about 20% so this will probably work fine). It should allow you to select most any country if used with its default locales data. Set a name, % and the country. Add an additional rate beneath that to set a global rate for all other locations (if different)